# ¿como evitar entrar a paginas mediante la url sin logearse?

Tags: php, php7, sesiones

Estoy comenzando en este mundo de la programación, estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto, el problema que tengo es al momento de copiar la URL me deja acceder al panel administrador, con solo copiar la URL, de que manera puedo controlarlo. Este es la manera que manejo el inicio de sesión, quizás no sea la mejor forma.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conexion.php');

$usu    = $_POST["txtusuario"];
$pass   = $_POST["txtpassword"];
$rol    = $_POST["rol"];

$queryusuario = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usu' and pass = '$pass' and rol = '$rol'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($queryusuario);  
    
if ($nr == 1 )  
    { 
        if($rol=="Usuario")
            {                   
                header("Location: pag_user.php");
            }
        if($rol=="Operador")
            {               
                header("Location: pag_user.php");
            }           
        else if ($rol=="Admin")
            {
                header("Location: pag_admin.php");
            }
        else if ($rol=="Dir")
            {
                header("Location: pag_admin.php");
            }
        else if ($rol=="Infor")
            {
                header("Location: pag_admin.php");
            }
        else if ($rol=="Dev")
            {
                header("Location: pag_admin.php");
            }
    }
else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Usuario o contrasena incorrectos");</script>'; 
        echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Para controlar que no se pueda acceder a la pagina del del panel administrador tendras que realizar el control de quien es el que accede en el archivo .php de esa pagina, en este caso creo que es pag_admin.php. Para controlar esto puedes utilizar sessiones de php para saber quien es el usuario o persona que esta intentando acceder a dicha pagina y comprobar si este es o no es administrador, de esta forma en caso de no serlo mandarle a otro lado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar ese error, primero deberías generar un formulario para la correcta validación del  usuario.(No aclaras y estas usando un Formulario).

Al momento de validar los Datos, cuando re direcciones la pagina
Crea la $_SESSION

```
$_SESSION['usuario']='usuario';
```

En la pagina donde validas si es Admin,User,etc debes poner lo siguiente

```
session_start();
$varsesion= $_SESSION['usuario'];
if ($varsesion == null || $varsesion= '' ){ // Aquí estamos validando si se envió correctamente la sesion, si no se envio que me redireccione a al formulario.

session_destroy();
  echo "<a href='../index.php'>Volver</a>";
  die();
 
}
```

Aquí puedes ver la [documentacion oficial](https://ttps://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)